# what is the througput controller on jmeter and their examples ?

Tags: jmeter

Can any body explain me, what is the purpose & uses of the through put controller on load testing web applications ? why there is a option for the per user? give some examples ?

Answer (score 0):

Think on the CTT as a way of keeping the total throughput (hits/m) of you test scenario.

Let's say that you have a test plan which runs 100 users. In our example, the test plan can hit the site with up to 500 hits per minute, but you want to control it, so you set the CTT to 100 hits. Doing so the Jmeter engine will do it's own calcs to control it (by adding timers to the test).
http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer
A very good usage of this timer is also explained in the Jmeter community. They explain how you can control the throughput of your test during the load test. So if your app can handle the 100 hits/m you defined, and you want to test it under 200 hits/m, you can do it without stopping the test, change it, and start again!
http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html

The per-user option is to change the hits/m ratio of the entire test, or of a specific user.

Hope it helps :)